# Unable to print index at the beginning of the document

Tags: cross-referencing, indexing

I am trying to compile a 'Table of Cases' and 'Table of Statutes' in the form of an index which should go before the main text.

I am using the Oscola package, Biber, and imakeidx to put together the indices, but they will not show at the beginning of the document.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you can compile the index at the end, and then use an \inputgraphics insertion of the index output at the beginning of the document in a second run? I think the index simply isn't ready on the first run to be inserted because the document must run until the end first, to make the index.

Comment: Thank you, Guido. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: The “automatic” feature of `imakeidx` can work only if the indices are at the very end. Use the `noautomatic` option and run MakeIndex manually.

Comment: Thanks. How would I run `imakeidx` manually?

Comment: @OrestesAdamou: Running `makeindex` depends on the OS you are using.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer How would that be on a windows terminal?

Comment: @OrestesAdamou: I just checked it, running on Windows is the same as on Linux. Say, your document is called `foo.tex`, then a `foo.idx` will be generated by LaTeX and `imakeidx`. Just open a terminal in the correct directory (where foo.tex and foo.idx are stored) and say `makeindex foo`. This should be sufficient. Run (pdf)latex again afterwards

Answer (score 2):

This problem is explained in the `oscola` documentation, and the package provides a command for this purpose:

```
\printindexearly[<indexname>] 
% e.g., cases; depends on earlier usage of \makeindex
```

In this case, you cannot rely on `imakeidx`, but must build the index manually.  The sequence of commands is:

```sh
latex myfile.tex # or: pdflatex | xelatex | lualatex
biber myfile.bcf 
latex myfile.tex
latex myfile.tex # run twice to resolve all cross-references
# then either `makeindex` or `splitindex`
# makeindex:
makeindex <indexname> -s oscola # run on each `.idx` file generated that needs oscola formatting
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a final `latex myfile` at the end?