# Index at beginning of document: imakeidx

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I'm trying to create a document with two indices, one of which must appear near the very beginning. There are two old questions about this sort of thing [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193460/unable-to-print-index-at-the-beginning-of-the-document) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136825/index-at-the-beginning-of-a-document). A solution seems to be to use the `imakeidx` package with the option `noautomatic`, and then compile manually. Consider:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{book}

\usepackage[noautomatic]{imakeidx}

\makeindex
\makeindex[name=other,title=Other One]

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
Blah.
\printindex[other]

\mainmatter
Here is some text \index[other]{Text}.
Here is some more text \index{More text}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

When I run `MakeIndex`, it produces both .idx files, but when I compile after that, only the main index is printed.

What's the simplest way to make sure that the index in the frontmatter gets printed?

I'm using TexLive with TexStudio on Windows 10.